# Install DLL with regasm witouth cmd window

Tags: nsis, regasm

I'm trying to create a installer that uses regasm.exe to install my DLL but it open the black cmd window and i don't wan't to show it.
My code looks like:

`ExecWait "$MyPath\RegAsm.exe" /tlb /register /codebase /nologo /silent "$MyOtherPath\MyDLL.dll"`

It doesn't write anything but it open the window. I use NSIS to create the installer

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecWait` will display the console when you run console programs, if you don't want that then you have to use a plug-in like [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt) (part of NSIS), [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) or [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in):

```
nsExec::Exec '"$MyPath\RegAsm.exe" /tlb /register /codebase /nologo /silent "$MyOtherPath\ShellContextMenu.dll"'
Pop $0 ; Process exit code or "error" in $0
```